# How can we shift all child elements to right side alignment inside multi select checkbox dropdown list in Angular?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I need help on below scenarios,

I have one multiselect dropdownlist which using ng-multiselect-dropdown control in Angular and my Parent and Child items binding in it using below line of code in html file,

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown name="Countries" 
            [data]="Countries"  
            [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries"
            [settings]="dropdownSettings">
 </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

DropdownSettings code in TS file as below,

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
                singleSelection: false,
                idField: 'item_id',
                textField: 'item_text',
                selectAllText: 'Select All',
                unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
                allowSearchFilter: true                
            };
```

I want to give right intendent to all child items which are display in dropdown list which uses 'ng-multiselect-dropdown' package as mentioned in above code So, How can we do that and what code I need to add or modify to shift my all child elements to the right hand side inside dropdownlsit?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom CSS to indent child items. First, add a `customTemplate` to your `<ng-multiselect-dropdown>` component:

```html
<ng-multiselect-dropdown name="Countries" 
            [data]="Countries"  
            [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries"
            [settings]="dropdownSettings">
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
    <div [ngClass]="{'indent-class': item.isChild}">
      {{ item.item_text }}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Then, in your CSS file, add the `indent-class`:

```css
.indent-class {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Finally, modify your data to include an `isChild` flag:

```js
Countries = [
  { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Parent1', isChild: false },
  { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Child1', isChild: true },
  // ...
];
```

This will indent all items with `isChild: true` by 20 pixels.